# How do I debug ASP.NET app with VS without loading dlls into Temporary ASP.NET file directory

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I have a (web) project that has a dependency on a dll (we'll call it `runtime.dll`) that requires a specific xml (we'll call it `runtime.xml`) file be found in the same place as the dll.  When I debug this project in VS 2017, all the dlls are isolated individually under `Temporary ASP.NET Files`, and `runtime.dll`can't find its `runtime.xml`.  It's not a problem during build - they both end up together.  How can I configure the project so these are located properly for debugging?  Or, perhaps another question is how can I run the debugging out of `/bin`?

Comment: A work-around (may not be possible in your context) would be to have your runtime.dll check an environment variable like RUNTIME_XML_PATH and use that path.  When the environment variable is not set, it defaults to looking in the same directory as runtime.dll.

Comment: yeah, I neglected to mention that it's a 3rd party dependency and I don't have control over the code